# How to connect to existing hyperledger network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy a business network archive (.bna) file to an existing hyperledger fabric network. I have started the network using the fabric samples/first-network as a hyperledger network by following the guide http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html. But I dont have any clue to import the .bna into the hyperledger network.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using v1.0.x of fabric you will need Composer v0.16.x and you can go through this [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org) to understand the steps though your experience will be a little different as you have your own Fabric already running.

If you are using fabric v1.1.0-alpha then you will need Composer v0.17.6 and an updated [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org).

You don't say if you have created the .bna file from the Playground or from the CLI.  If you have created from the Playground then you will need to install the Composer CLI to follow the tutorial commands.  The CLI install information can be found [here for v0.16.x](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) or [here for v0.17.6](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/installing/development-tools.html).